# How do i make "display:none;" apply to containing elements of div awell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide some content and have it only appear when something is selected in a `<select>` field.

From what I understand, I need to hide the content as a start, so I am trying to do this:

```
      <div id="abc" style="display:none;">
       <tr> <!-- Third row -->
        <td>
            from
        </td>

        <td>
           <select name="serv" id="serv" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">

                <option value="US" name="US">Some other US option</option>
                <option value="US" name="US">some US option</option>

            </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </div>
```

This only hides the `<div>` and not its content.

Comment: I'd love to see a demo of this as something else must be going on. If your ABC div is set to display none I assure you, nothing inside of it will be visible.

Comment: TR as a child of a DIV? Who told you that? Invalid HTML enables unexpected behavior.

Comment: ahh... that might have something to do with it. I wonder if the browser is self closing your div because of your malformed HTML?

Comment: I do have a table, i didnt post it all, cause it's a lot of irelevant code

Comment: the <div> itself is gone, when i inspect it with firebug, but the content remains, i am using bootstrap css, il try to add !important to see if their settings are tampering with it

Comment: @JohnDoe A TR element cannot be a direct child of a DIV element. The code you posted above is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers parse this code

```
<table>
    <div>
        <tr>
            <td>TABLE CELL</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

into this structure

[image: screen shot]

Notice how the DIV does **not** wrap your table row, but is placed **before** the table (as a adjacent sibling). Therefore, if you hide the DIV, the table row won't be hidden with it.

Invalid HTML enables unexpected behavior. Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That `<div>` doesn't look right there. I assume you have a `<table>` tag somewhere else in your code but you haven't pasted it here.

You could try applying the style to the `<tr>` tag. Children of an element should always inherit that element's style so your misplaced `<div>` tag might be the problem. Try this instead:

```
<tr id="abc" style="display:none;"> <!-- Third row -->
    <td>
        from
    </td>

    <td>
       <select name="serv" id="serv" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">

            <option value="US" name="US">Some other US option</option>
            <option value="US" name="US">some US option</option>

        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Works when i apply it to the <tr> but there are no misplaced <div> tags as of what i can see, anyway thanks

Comment: I meant misplaced in the sense that your `<div>` probably shouldn't be wrapping a table row `<tr>`. Either it should wrap the whole table or it should be inside a particular cell. Neither would help you hide an entire row though, so it's probably best to stick with putting the information in your `<tr>` tag as suggested. Hope this makes sense.